# Package release 'Locale_Mage_community_el_GR' not found on server'

Tags: magento-1.9, language, language-package

I am trying to install the greek language pack through the `magento` connect manager and i always get the following error:

```
community/Locale_Mage_community_el_GR: Package release 'Locale_Mage_community_el_GR' not found on server: No releases for 'Locale_Mage_community_el_GR: Package release 'Locale_Mage_community_el_GR' not found on server', skipping
```

I know the extension is in beta version so i changed the preferred state from the `magento's` connect manager settings, but the error still remains.
What can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: Download the package and apply proper deployment (bypass Connect Manager).

- [Magento Extension Downloader](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php)
- [Firegento Composer Repository](http://packages.firegento.com/#!/locale_mage_community_el_gr)

Option 2: Try via command line (see [WebShopApps blog post](http://www.webshopapps.com/blog/2011/08/installing-community-extensions-via-command-line-ssh/)).

```
$ ./mage config-show
…
preferred package state        preferred_state      beta
…

$ ./mage install connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Locale_Mage_community_el_GR
…
Package community/Locale_Mage_community_el_GR 1.0.19870.4.2 installed successfully
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer to why doesn't work, but I may have a solution to your problem. You can get any language pack [from here](https://github.com/versedi/Magento-Locales/). Versedi did a nice job gathering every language pack available on Magento 1.